# Quoting a quotation mark

Tags: sql, plsql

My code

```
declare
  vnm varchar(20);
  vt varchar(100);
begin
  select ename 
  into vnm
  from emp
  where empno=0;
exception
  when others then
    dbms_output.put_line('Employee ID doesn't exist');
  vt := sqlerrm;
  insert into errlog values(vt,sysdate);
  commit;
end;
/
```

I'm getting quoted string not terminated properly error and i corrected insert statement values with single inverted comma but still i m getting same error so anyone help with this please

Comment: Oracle will tell you the line number the error is on. And I would guess with near 100% certainty it's in your dbms_output.put_line statement. You have an apostrophe between n and t in the message.

Comment: Thanks for the help i got it......

Answer (score 0):

Use a single quotation in front if you want the same to be printed, i.e.

```
dbms_output.put_line('Employee ID doesn''t exist');
```